# SQL Server : add two times together and append to given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server : add two times together and append to given date

[image]

Here `startTime` is `varchar`

- `sd` means startDate
- `ed` means endDate

Required new columns are:

- 1. `sd + startTime`    Ex: 2015-06-09 23:00
- 2. `ed + (startTime + duration)`    Ex: 2015-08-23 00:30

please notice time clearly here.

Thank you

Comment: you want to show it or you want to update it in database

Comment: I need this with select query  @AmeyaDeshpande

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type; for a date&time, that's `TIME`, `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2(n)` - but **definitely NOT** `varchar` - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: sd is type of date or varchar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you need something like this :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @sd        Date
        ,@time      Varchar(5)
        ,@ed        Date
        ,@Duration  Varchar(8)

Select   @sd = '2015-06-09'
        ,@time = '23:00'
        ,@ed = '2015-08-22'
        ,@Duration = '01:30:00'

Select   Cast(@time As Datetime) + Cast(@sd As Datetime) As startdate
        ,Cast(@ed As Datetime) + Cast(@time As Datetime) + Cast(@Duration As Datetime) As enddate
```

**EDIT:-**

```
Set Nocount On;

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#DateTimeTogather') Is Not Null
Begin   
    Drop Table #DateTimeTogather;
End

Create Table #DateTimeTogather
(
     scheduleId             Int Primary Key
    ,startTime              Varchar(5)
    ,sd                     Date
    ,programId              Int
    ,ed                     Date
    ,duration               Time
)

Insert Into #DateTimeTogather(scheduleId,startTime,sd,programId,ed,duration) Values
 (20,'23:00','2015-06-09',50,'2015-08-22','01:30:00')
,(21,'09:00','2015-06-07',29,'2015-08-22','00:45:00')
,(22,'14:00','2015-06-06',14,'2015-08-22','00:35:00')
,(23,'17:30','2015-06-13',7,'2015-06-13','00:45:00')
,(24,'19:00','2015-06-06',65,'2015-06-27','00:30:00')
,(25,'10:00','2015-06-06',81,'2015-06-17','04:12:00')
,(26,'17:00','2015-06-06',7,'2015-06-27','00:45:00')
,(27,'12:30','2015-06-06',7,'2015-06-27','00:45:00')

Select   dt.scheduleId
        ,Cast(dt.sd As Datetime) + Cast(dt.startTime As Datetime) As startdate
        ,Cast(dt.ed As Datetime) + Cast(dt.startTime As Datetime) + Cast(dt.duration As Datetime) As enddate
From    #DateTimeTogather As dt With (Nolock)
```

this gives no error

Comment: getting error 
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: need datatypes of each columns then i can tell you something or guide you something

Comment: `Declare  @sd        Date
        ,@time      Varchar(5)
        ,@ed        Date
        ,@Duration  time`

Comment: It is showing conversion error my side please check my **SQL Query**
`select a.programId, a.duration , b.scheduleId, b.time,Cast(b.time As Datetime) as convertedTime, b.repeated from tbProgram a left join tbSchedule b on a.programId=b.programId  where b.scheduleId is not NULL `
a.time is Varchar(15) when  trying to convert this with Cast(b.time As Datetime) as convertedTime getting conversion error.

Comment: need exact table design of both tables tbProgram and tbSchedule and with few sample data of both tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80974/discussion-between-manikanta-g-and-mihir-shah).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given that you are a varchar datatype I'm going to have to ignore that and assume your sd column reads dd-mmm-yyyy 00:00:00.  If its SQL Server 2008+ you can use the code below to give the date at midnight.

```
CONVERT(DATE,sd, 101)
```

After all dates and times are converted correctly the query below should do it:

```
SELECT (sd + starttime) as StartDatetime, (sd + startTime + duration) as EndDateTime
```